# vis.js_timeline/REACTjs/JS: Display multiple items in one tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I am using the following code to pass content an array of items:

`const nArray = data.abs.map((abs, index) => ({id: index + 1, content: abs.Des[0], start: abs.time, title: abs.Trace, end: null, group: 1}))`

However, right now only the first item in the array is being displayed on the timeline. content looks as follows:

```
content:(5) ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item4"]
```

In the display, how do I display all the items in one tab on the timeline?

**UPDATE:**

Console log is showing the correct structure but receiving this error:

**Property "start" missing in item [object Object]**

`const nArray = data.abs.map((abs, index) => abs.Event.map((Event, index) =>({id: index + 1, content: Event, start: abs.timestamp, title: abstraction.Trace, end: null, group: 1})))`

**2nd Update**

The code below now has this error which seems to be coming from the vis.js library but I'm not sure what it means:

**Uncaught TypeError: i is not a function**

`const nArray = data.abs.map((abs, index) => ({id: index + 1, content: abs.Event.map((Event, index) => ({id: index + 1, Event})), start: abs.timestamp, title: abs.Trace, end: null, group: 1}))`

Answer (score 1):

The fix I used was to convert the array to a StringArray with the `toString()` function.  I changed my code from the above to the following which displays whatever values are stored in the array.

Fix:

`const nArray = data.abs.map((abs, index) => ({id: index + 1, content: abs.Event.toString(), start: abs.timestamp, title: abs.Trace, end: null, group: 1}))`